# bind variable substitution in oracle

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

The below simple procedure is suppose to provide grants to the user scott in oracle.

The value for &scott_SCHEMA is already defined in a seperate file(define_variable.sql) and the value is getting substituted correctly, but im getting the error(as specified in the bottom of the script), a help is much appreciated.

```
 SET SERVEROUTPUT ON 
declare

  l_sql varchar2(3200);  
begin
   for i in ( select table_name as oname,'TABLE' as type from all_tables where owner='HR' AND table_name not like  'BIN$%' union all  select view_name as oname,'VIEW' as type from all_views where owner='HR' and view_name not like  'BIN$%' )
   loop
      if i.type = 'TABLE' then
        dbms_output.put_line(l_sql);
         l_sql:= 'grant select,insert,update,delete on hr.'||i.oname||' to :owner with grant option';
         execute immediate l_sql using '&scott_SCHEMA';
        else
         l_sql:= 'grant select on hr.'||i.oname||' to :owner with grant option';

      end if;

   end loop;
end;
/

*declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00987: missing or invalid username(s)
ORA-06512: at line 12*
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use bind variables in place of identifiers (specifically schema or object names) in DDL or DML statements, they can only be used in place of value expressions.

Since you're using substitution variables, you could just place it in the sql statement itself:

```
l_sql:= 'grant select,insert,update,delete on hr.'||i.oname||' to &scott_SCHEMA with grant option';
```

and execute it with out passing it as a parameter:

```
execute immediate l_sql;
```

On a side note, your DBMS_OUTPUT line should come after you assignment to l_sql, otherwise you'll miss outputting one or more of the statements being processed.  A good place would be between the assignment statement and the execute statement.